# Recursive code works for string but not with lists when given as parameter

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures, python-3.6

I am writing a recursive code to generate all the binary strings of length n with no consecutive 1s.

Logic : Our recursive function works as follows: Check the last element in the array. If the last element in array is 0 we can add a 0 or 1 at the end of the array. If the last element is 1 we can add only 0 and not 1 because if we add 1 and the last element is also 1 we will violate the condition that there must be no consecutive 1 in the solution. Once the length of the string is equal to N we add the array to our answer array.

I tried implementing the logic using lists to store 0s and 1s as parameter but it doesn't work. But when I used strings to store the 0's and 1's it gave correct solution.

Below are the snippets of two function with lists and strings used to store 0s and 1s respectively.

```
def generateString(N: int):
    def helper(i,n,arr,an):
        if i ==n:
            ans.append(arr.copy())
            return 
        if arr[i-1] == 1:
            arr.append(0)
            helper(i+1,n,arr,an)
        if arr[i-1] == 0:
            arr.append(0)
            helper(i+1,n,arr,an)
            arr.pop()
            arr.append(1)
            helper(i+1,n,arr,an)       
    a = [0] 
    ans = []
    helper(1,N,a,ans)
    a = [1]
    helper(1,N,a,ans)
    return ans

print(generateString(3))       
output : [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1]]
expected : [[0,0,0][0,0,1][0,1,0][1,0,0][1,0,1]]
```

```
def generateString(N: int):
    def helper(i,n,arr,an):
        if i == n:
            an.append(arr)
            return
        if arr[i-1] == "1":
            arr += "0"
            helper(i+1,n,arr,an)
        if arr[i-1] == "0":
            arr += "0"
            helper(i+1,n,arr,an)
            arr = arr[:-1]
            arr += "1"
            helper(i+1,n,arr,an)       
    a = "0"
    an = []
    helper(1,N,a,an)
    a = "1"
    helper(1,N,a,an)
    return an

print(generateString(3))       
output : ['000', '001', '010', '100', '101']
expected : ['000', '001', '010', '100', '101']
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem here is the old Python problem of forgetting that lists are mutable.  The `arr` in your `helper` function is always the same list, at every level.  That means when you modify it, you need to clean it up.  Your `if ... == 0` branch was leaving an extra 1 at the end.

This works:

```
def generateString(N: int):
    def helper(n,arr,an):
        if len(arr) == 3:
            an.append(arr.copy())
            return 
        arr.append(0)
        helper(n,arr,an)
        if arr[-2] == 0:
            arr[-1] = 1
            helper(n,arr,an)       
        arr.pop()

    ans = []
    helper(N,[0],ans)
    helper(N,[1],ans)
    return ans

print(generateString(3))
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1]]
```

Note that you don't actually need the "call it twice" hack, as long as you special case inside the function:

```
def generateString(N: int):
    def helper(n,arr,an):
        if len(arr) == 3:
            an.append(arr.copy())
            return 
        arr.append(0)
        helper(n,arr,an)
        if len(arr) == 1 or arr[-2] == 0:
            arr[-1] = 1
            helper(n,arr,an)       
        arr.pop()

    ans = []
    helper(N,[],ans)
    return ans

print(generateString(3))
```

And the code gets even simpler if you don't try to modify the list in place:

```
def generateString(N: int):
    def helper(n,arr,an):
        if len(arr) == 3:
            an.append(arr.copy())
        else:
            helper(n,arr+[0],an)
            if not arr or arr[-1] == 0:
                helper(n,arr+[1],an)       

    ans = []
    helper(N,[],ans)
    return ans

print(generateString(3))
```

Comment: Thanks man, really appreciate it. You've always been there on this part of web, whenever i have posted questions. Keep up the good work, we need you helping us.

Comment: Remember to mark the answer as accepted if you're satisfied.

Comment: In your last version, appending a copy is pointless.

Comment: I did understood your solutions but didnt got the : 
"The arr in your helper function is always the same list, at every level. That means when you modify it, you need to clean it up
why does always same list mean here and cleaning it." It would be really helpful if u could use my own code. Thank you so much beforehand

Comment: You should compare the length to n, not to 3. (You could also simplify the helper further  to `def helper(are):`, using N/ans instead of n/an).

Comment: @KellyBundy can u also look at my code. Not able to understand why code with list doesnt work but with string does

Comment: @ShashankMingwal Tim already explained that. And you were already aware that you're working with a single list object, that's why you call `.copy()`, remember? It's unclear why you have trouble understanding the issue of the missing pop.

Comment: You append a 0, then you pop it, then you append a 1, and you leave it.  Now, the next time `helper` gets called, that list will have an extra `1` in it, and future calls will add yet another one.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt to keep it simple, avoid "pop" and avoid copying unless necessary:

```
def generateString(N):
    answer = []

    def helper(array):
        if len(array) == N:
            answer.append(array)
        else:
            if not array or array[-1] == 0:
                helper([*array, 1])

            array.append(0)
            helper(array)

    helper([])

    return answer
```

print(generateString(3))

**OUTPUT**

```
% python3 test.py
[[1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0]]
%
```